# Elasticsearch Highlights are Slow

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a text index whose highlights are very slow. The queries themselves execute in a 100 milliseconds at the most, but highlighting afterwards can make it so that the response times shoot up to 90 seconds. I indexed elastic with `term_vector: with_positions_offsets`, and I have several questions in that regard

1. `plain` highlighting is still faster than `fvh` or `unified` highlighting (although `unified` should default to `fvh` in the presence of `term_vector: with_positions_offsets`, and it seems like `unified` highlighting is the slowest option of all three). Why is that?
2. Would preloading data into the filesystem cache help reduce highlighting time?